# Comparar arquivo do Working Directory com arquivo de repositório remoto

Tags: git, github

Como comparar um arquivo local, no Working Directory, com um arquivo existente em um repositório remoto, por exemplo GitHub?

Preciso identificar as mudanças realizadas em um arquivo local comparando com a versão no GitHub. Ainda não executei o comando **git add** sobre este arquivo, portanto ainda está no Working Directory.

Comment: `git diff` não funciona?

Comment: Tente executar o respondido na seguinte pergunta:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1800787/3797668

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imaginando que você está trabalhando na branch *master* no remote chamado *origin*, ficaria assim:

1. Atualizar sua branch master com as últimas alterações no GitHub

   `git fetch origin master`
2. Fazer o diff para ver o que foi alterado entre os arquivos no
   *working directory* e na *master*:

   `git diff origin/master`